# NHibernate will not insert a record

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, insert

I have an application that is now 4+ years old that is exhibiting some odd behavior on our latest deployment.  The application uses nHibernate for all inserts / updates / selects, etc. We are currently using .NET 2.0, and nHibernate 1.2 (I know, we need to upgrade)

This deployment is on Windows 2008 Server x64, IIS 7.5 - what I have seen so far is that the application runs, but is unable to insert or update records in the DB - reads seem fine so far, but writes are a problem.  SOME writes actually work, inserts into some small tables, but most never even make it to the DB.

Using SQL Profiler, the insert / updates never make it to the server, and turning log4net up to DEBUG, and show_sql true - the select statements appear, but the insert / update statements never make it into the log at all, and never show up at the server.

What's even more odd is that the application seems to be oblivious to this - the commandandclose runs without exception (open session in view with an httpmodule), the domain objects come back with uuid's generated, etc. but never get persisted.

Certainly an upgrade is due, but I would hate to try it during a deployment, and without time to accurately test the app.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both good answers, the problem was in the deployment.  The web.config was setup for IIS6, and the deployment to IIS7 did not properly setup the open session in view HttpModule that is used to commit the transaction.  Changing the pipeline mode from Integrated to Classic solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the default ISession FlushMode has been changed from Auto to Never or Commit. Never means that the session will flush when Flush() is called by the application; Commit means that the session will flush when a transaction is committed.

Answer (score 1):

Back out your current deployment and return to what you had before. Then look for the mistake someone made. If it used to insert and now does not, then something is wrong with your current code. If it isn't creating the insert/update statments, then I'd look first at where they are supposed to be created. Did the current deplyment actually insert record or update them in dev? Did anybody test that or were you relying onthe fact that it didn;t pop up an error? If it did work in dev and doesn't work in prod, I'd look at the envirnmental differnences between dev and prod.